# Sending transaction to Uniswap/Pancakeswap Router using Nethereum failing

Tags: uniswap, pancakeswap, nethereum

I'm trying to send a transaction to the Uniswap or Pancakeswap V3 router using Nethereum for a token swap via "exactInputSingle", but first I'm performing a gas estimate for the transaction. However, its fails with an exception "execution reverted: eth_estimateGas". I made sure I called the "approve" method of the spending token but still with the same result.

Could use some direction as to what I could be doing wrong! Estimating gas via the same methodology for the token approve on the spending token's contract worked fine.

It also took me a while to figure out that exactInputSingle expects a struct with the following parameters:

```
struct ExactInputSingleParams {
        address tokenIn;
        address tokenOut;
        uint24 fee;
        address recipient;
        uint256 deadline;
        uint256 amountIn;
        uint256 amountOutMinimum;
        uint160 sqrtPriceLimitX96;
    }
```

This led to having to provide a nested array as the input parameter for "GetData". But not sure this is the issue as the resulting hex output shows there are 8 encoded input parameters concatenated which looks correct. Here is the affected code snippet:

```
     //Get the exactInputSingle function from contract (retrieved via pancakeswap router address + abi)
     var routerContract = web3.Eth.GetContract(dexInfo.dexRouterAbi, "0x13f4EA83D0bd40E75C8222255bc855a974568Dd4");
     var exactInputSingleFunction = routerContract.GetFunction("exactInputSingle");

     var deadline = new BigInteger(((DateTimeOffset)DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(1)).ToUnixTimeSeconds());

     // Encode the function call data
     var encodedSwapCall = exactInputSingleFunction.GetData(new object[]{ new object[] {
         spendingTokenAddress,           //address = string
         receivingTokenAddress,          //address = string
         fee,                            //uint24 = int32
         walletAddress,                  //address = string, my wallet address
         deadline,                       //uint256 = BigInteger, from unix timestamp
         spendingTokenAmountBaseUnits,   //uint256 = BigInteger
         new BigInteger(0),              //uint256 = BigInteger
         new BigInteger(0)               //uint256 = BigInteger
     } });

     //Estimate gas            
     var callInput = new CallInput()
     {
         From = walletAddress,                               //My address
         To = "0x13f4EA83D0bd40E75C8222255bc855a974568Dd4",  //Pancakeswap router address
         Data = encodedSwapCall
     };

     //Exception thrown here: "execution reverted: eth_estimateGas"
     var gasUnitsLimitEstimate = await web3.Eth.TransactionManager.EstimateGasAsync(callInput);
```

Edit: I skipped the gas estimation and went straight to sending it. The transaction expectedly fails, but the data seems to have gone through.

https://bscscan.com/tx/0x1564913cb6936fadf12e3685a0e4cf03b755e3fe48dd18c67f996ac62578fba4

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the issue might be with the input parameters being passed to the `exactInputSingle` function. One thing you can try is to encode the nested array of input parameters manually using the `AbiEncoder` class from Nethereum.

Here is an example of how to manually encode the nested array of input parameters using the `AbiEncoder` class:

```csharp
using Nethereum.Hex.HexConvertors.Extensions;
using Nethereum.ABI.Encoders;
using Nethereum.ABI.FunctionEncoding;
using Nethereum.Hex.HexTypes;

// ...

// Define the input parameters
var inputParams = new object[] {
    spendingTokenAddress,
    receivingTokenAddress,
    fee,
    walletAddress,
    deadline,
    spendingTokenAmountBaseUnits,
    new BigInteger(0),
    new BigInteger(0)
};

// Define the input parameter types
var inputTypes = new Type[] {
    typeof(address),
    typeof(address),
    typeof(uint24),
    typeof(address),
    typeof(uint256),
    typeof(uint256),
    typeof(uint256),
    typeof(uint256)
};

// Encode the nested array of input parameters using the AbiEncoder class
var encoder = new ABIEncoderV2();
var encodedParams = encoder.EncodeParameters(inputTypes, inputParams).ToHex();

// Encode the function call data
var encodedSwapCall = exactInputSingleFunction.GetData(encodedParams);
```

This should encode the nested array of input parameters correctly for the `exactInputSingle` function.

If this does not solve the issue, you can try adding more error handling around the call to `EstimateGasAsync` to get more information about the exception being thrown. For example, you can catch the `RpcResponseException` and check the `Result` property to see the error message returned by the Ethereum node.